# Replacing old dimmer with a new one

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, safety

I bought a dimmer on Amazon.  The ASIN number is B002DN2PGY.  It has two black wires and one green.  The old dimmer only has two wires, one black and one red.  It is connected to two wires, one orange and one gray.  I can see the black wire goes to the gray and the red goes to the orange.  There aren't any other wires like ground wires inside the wall box.  Where do I connect the green wire to? am I supposed to ground the green to the metal enclosure of the wall.  If I shouldn't do that, what should I do with the green wire? My townhouse has 1985 wiring.  [image]
[image]

Comment: 85 wiring should have ground.  Quite possible they use metal conduit which is the ground path instead of a wire.  Connecting the green wire to the box should be the way, unless the instructions say something else.

Answer (score 2):

The green wire is earth ground and should be connected to the metal box. The other two do not matter it should work either way. If not just swap them.If your metal box is not grounded you can check with the local authority to find out what you need to do.